# R httr package to point external browser

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, httr, google-fit

I have a script that request Google authentication for GoogleFit API usint `httr` package:

```
library(httr)
library(RGoogleFit)

google_client <- gargle::gargle_oauth_client_from_json("client_secret_xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json")

myapp <- httr::oauth_app(appname = "myapp", key = google_client$id, secret = google_client$secret)

google_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("google"), myapp,
                               scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read",
                               cache = "httr-oauth")

currentToken<-google_token$credentials$access_token
n<-GetFitDataset(currentToken,"derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-05-01")),as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-06-04")))
```

If I execute that scripts in my pc (windows), it opens a browser in my pc for Google login, so I can authenticate.

What I want is **this script to be available for any user to execute** (not only me).
I tried by creating an app in **shinyapps.io**, but nothing happens and I see in logs:

```
2023-06-12T06:16:32.236703+00:00 shinyapps[9290112]: Please point your browser to the following url: 
2023-06-12T06:16:32.236759+00:00 shinyapps[9290112]: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Any tip for achieving this?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, I just need the token to use GoogleFit API later. After some investigation on oauth2 dance and shiny I got the way how to point external browser and get the token. I need this app to be executed in local or deployed in shinyapps and send its url to some user. The app will ask the user to authenticate and the token will be received internally:

```
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(RGoogleFit)

if (Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT') == ""){
  #LOCAL
  print("Local")
  myPort=8080
  options(shiny.port = myPort)
  APP_URL<-"http://localhost:8080/"
  
} else {
  #SHINYAPPS.IO
  print("shinyapps.io")
  APP_URL <- "https://mydomain.shinyapps.io/myapp/"
}

# web
google_client <- gargle::gargle_oauth_client_from_json("client_secret_xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com.json")

app <- httr::oauth_app(appname = "myapp", key = google_client$id, secret = google_client$secret,redirect_uri = APP_URL)
api <- oauth_endpoints("google")
scope <- "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

url_has_param <- function(params,code) {return(!is.null(params[[code]]))}


uiFunc <- function(req) {
  
  params<-parseQueryString(req$QUERY_STRING)
  
  if (!url_has_param(params,"code")) {
    
    url <- oauth2.0_authorize_url(api, app, scope = scope)
    #Make it offline
    url <- paste0(url,"&access_type=offline&prompt=consent")
    
    redirect <- sprintf("location.replace(\"%s\");", url)
    tags$script(HTML(redirect))
    
  } else {
    
    body=list(
      client_id=google_client$id,
      client_secret=google_client$secret,
      code = params$code,
      grant_type="authorization_code",
      redirect_uri=APP_URL
    )
    
    response<-httr::POST("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",body=body,encode="form")
    responseToken<-content(response,"parsed")
    
    ###############
    # Do what you want with the token
    ################
    print("responseToken")
    print(responseToken)
    
    # for example get GoogleFitAPi data:
    n<-GetFitDataset(responseToken$access_token,"derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-05-01")),as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-06-04")))
    
  }
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  params <- parseQueryString(isolate(session$clientData$url_search))
  if (!url_has_param(params,"code")){return()}
  
}

# Note that we're using uiFunc, not ui!
shinyApp(uiFunc, server)
```